# Do I have referential integrity in this schema design?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, relational-database, relationship

[image]

I'm concerned that I have a data integrity issue involving the `Versions` and `VersionQuestions` tables. For example, if `DefMasterID` is changed in the `Versions` table, it will point to a different master definition, but the child records in `Questions` will still be pointing at records in the `MasterQuestionsPool` that belong to the original survey master. Ideally, the constraints would prevent this but I don't think they will.

Do I have integrity with this design? If not, what is the appropriate path to take to ensure integrity?

The above schema is based on these requirements:

1. There need to be multiple survey master definitions that represent significantly different surveys.
2. A master survey definition needs one or more versions, which represent small differences.
3. Each survey master has a pool of questions, which are shared between its versions. An individual version generally will not use all questions. This provides the ability to compare answers across all versions of a survey master.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right to be concerned.

One approach would be to add an identifier (call it something like MasterQuestionInstanceLabel) to the MasterQuestionsPool that is unique within a given pool (though not necessarily across pools).  In other words, the pairing of Question 1 with Master 1 might be labeled as question "A" (for Master 1), but Master 2 might have a different question "A".  Then, in the MasterVersionQuestions table, you use that label, rather than the actual question ID.

This fits a little better with reality, I think.  The idea is that you define a pool of questions for a given master -- questions A,B,C,D,E,F (which are labels for the actual ids 1, 5, 102, 15, and 754), and then say that version 1 uses A,B and E, while version 2 uses A,B,C and F (rather then reference the actual ids in the version table).

This way the version table isn't saying "which questions are in this version", it's saying "which of my master's pool instances are in this version".